# polars equivalent of postgres row_number over partition by

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to implement the same functionality of the row_number window function present in many db flavors in polars. I have tried this and it seems to work, but it looks overkill. Is there a better way to implement this ?

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"foo": [2,1,3,7,6,32], "tech": ['python', 'python', 'java','rust','c','rust'], "service": ["a","a","a","b","c","b"]}
)

q = (
    df
    .with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias('ones'))
    .select([pl.all().exclude('ones'),
             pl.col('ones').cumsum().over(['tech','service']).flatten().alias('rn')])
)

print(q)


shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬────────┬─────────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ tech   ┆ service ┆ rn  │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ str    ┆ str     ┆ i32 │
╞═════╪════════╪═════════╪═════╡
│ 2   ┆ python ┆ a       ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ python ┆ a       ┆ 2   │
│ 3   ┆ java   ┆ a       ┆ 1   │
│ 7   ┆ rust   ┆ b       ┆ 1   │
│ 6   ┆ c      ┆ c       ┆ 1   │
│ 32  ┆ rust   ┆ b       ┆ 2   │
└─────┴────────┴─────────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Looks like `.cumcount()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76884896/

Comment: thanks , that works. I would like to have the groups sorted so they are contiguous in the dataframe, i tried this `df.with_columns(rn = pl.col('foo').sort().cumcount().over(['tech','service']))` but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm guessing maybe that means: `.over(...).sort_by('foo')` - if you can edit in the expected output people can answer.